# Como criar uma função que divida dois números em C?

Tags: c, funções

Como criar uma função que divida dois números em C?

Comment: isso assim 5 / 2 = 2.50 ?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Comment: tô precisando de uma função em C que divida dois números  quaisquer

Comment: Poste algum código que você já tenha tentado fazer.

Comment: se alguma resposta te ajudou marque-a como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## include

int f_divisao(float num1, float num2)  /** criação da função **/
{
    float resultado;
    resultado=num1/num2;

```
printf("VALOR DA DIVISÃO DE %f / %f EH: %.2f\n",num1,num2,resultado);  /** saida de dados **/

return(f_divisao);
```

}

int main()
{

```
float num1,num2;

printf("DIGITE OS DOIS VALORES:\n");
scanf("%f%f",&num1,&num2);  /** entrada de dados **/

f_divisao(num1,num2);  /** retorna os valores para a função f_divisao **/
```

}
// Veja este que fiz!

Answer (score 1):

Mais resumidamente é assim ó:

```
float dividir(float a, float b)
{
float c=a/b;
return c;
}
```

Desse jeito eu coloquei função float no caso vai retornar um float pra main. Ai é só tu fazer a atribuição... tipo  `float d=dividir(a,b)`
Espero te-lo ajudado!

Comment: sim é isso mesmo

Comment: mas agora como eu chamo essa função no int main?

Comment: @IureRamos cria uma variável float... Exemplo:  float aux=dividir(a,b); Pressupõe que o a e b tu já tenha inicializado no programa. Depois pode dar um printf("%f",aux); para testar

Comment: deu certo, obrigado

Comment: mas eu tenho uma dúvida, para que eu preciso da função? eu não poderia só fazer o programa normal, sem a função?

Comment: Poder tu pode sim, mas na pergunta você pediu como criar uma função. Se for só no main é só fazer uma nova variável e atribuir a divisão @IureRamos  float c=a/b; basta se for na main()!

Comment: ah, entendi, tudo bem então

Answer (score 1):

[**ideone**](https://ideone.com/XexGsN)

```
int a = 5, b = 2;
float c = 0.0;
c = (float)a/b;
printf("%.1f", c);
return 0;
```

> `%.1f`  retorna com uma casa decimal `%.2f` com duas casas e etccc

Comment: Olá Leo gostei da sua resposta! A principio o "%.1f" é para escrever com uma casa depois da "," correto?

Comment: @Iure Ramos, resposta: https://ideone.com/61Bz41 :)